# Facebook AccountKit override onActivityResult on main activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, facebook-sdk-4.0, account-kit

I added custom footer to my `AccountKitActivity` screen.  It is possible according to [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing).

In my layout I added buttons as footer fragment, but I need to use `onActivityResult` after my buttons finish theirs action.
Is it possible to extends `com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity` so i will able to override the `onActivityResult` and add additional actions to facebook actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to extend this class. This is a design decision made for legal reasons